# Unable to start project server while using infinite while loop in python task schedule

Tags: python, django

If I'm using schedule module to execute a function for a pre-defned times used the following code to achieve this, but using this infinite while loop unable start project server. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
import schedule
import time

def test():
  # code write here

# function executes for every 10 mins
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(test())

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: server not starting still loading due to this infinite while loop

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427885/9374673). You should also include more information on exactly how you are integrating this code into a Django application. This is probably not the ideal way to achieve scheduling of tasks with Django.